# How can I use multible images for Django product model?

Tags: python, django, image

I want to create a online shop website in Django and I don't know how to make a model of product that can have many images. For example it can contain 0, 5 or even 50 Images. I don't want to write spagetti code with 10 image fields with blank=True + null=True. And by searching on the internet I have not found anything that can help me. So please just don't send other stackoverflow question. Also I will add a new product from Admin page not from templates :) hope this question is gonna be answered!

Comment: try this: `image = models.FileField(blank=True)`

Comment: I want many )))))

Answer (score 0):

If you will have uncertain amount of images for your product, then you have to create separate model for your images and connect it with your product through foregin key:

```py
class Product(models.Model):
    ...


class ProductImage(models.Model):
    product = models.ForeignKey(to=Product)
    value = models.ImageField()
```